# SQL query recursion for a web-like structure

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion

I have a table here, named "Foo". The data is set up something like this.

```
ID     TableReference     DataId0     DataId1     DataId2
--     --------------     -------     -------     -------
 1     Prize                   3           4           5
 2     Prize                   4           5        NULL
 3     Cash                    1        NULL        NULL
 4     Prize                   8        NULL          12
 5     Foo                     2           3        NULL
 6     Cash                    8           1          10
 7     Foo                     5           1           2
```

Etc. The data is horribly set up, I know, but I didn't set it up that way. :) I'm only dealing with the after effect.

I'm trying to come up with a way to essentially "flatten" the table; that is, to display all the data to a point where the table "Foo" does not reference itself. I'm trying to figure out a sql query that I can do to get there.

Usually when I deal with recursion, I have (or can establish) parent IDs and set it up that way, but for this table there are seemingly multiple child and parent IDs creating a web-like structure instead of a hierarchy. So I'm at a loss where to even begin to write a sql query for something like this.

Note: There is no infinite looping (where one Foo points to another Foo, which points back to the original Foo) from what I've found.

Using t-sql. Thanks for any assistance, if at all possible.

Comment: Removed `mysql` tag as this is unrelated to mysql.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to get to. Do you just want to display the data with the three numerical columns replaced with the equivalent TableReference values?

Comment: infinite loop 1 -> 3 -> 1 ?

Comment: Correct. The hang up is that the table (Foo) _can_ reference itself, possibly multiple times (Foo entry points to Foo entry, which points to another Foo entry).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step would be to present a normalized view of the underlying table. Give this schema:

```
create table dbo.foo
(
  id             int         not null primary key clustered ,
  TableReference varchar(64) not null ,
  DataId0        int         not null ,
  DataId1        int             null ,
  DataId2        int             null ,
)
```

You can say something like this:

```
with normalized_view as
(
        select id = id , TableReference = TableReference , DataId = DataId0 from dbo.foo
  union select id = id , TableReference = TableReference , DataId = DataId1 from dbo.foo
  union select id = id , TableReference = TableReference , DataId = DataId2 from dbo.foo 
)
select *
from normalized_view nv
```

Without knowing what `DataId[0-2]` reference, it's hard to go any further than that.

Comment: The dataId[0-2] reference other database tables, including Foo itself.

Comment: Then you should be able to go from what I've given you and write a normal recursive union.

Comment: I guess it will work if all other tables are added to the normailized_view. If you just want references that are not Pointing to  'Foo', you can join normalized_view with itself and filter out self-references in WHERE clause.

Comment: Yes, this works. It's funny how all it takes sometimes is just a different perspective.

Just flatten the table itself and do a recursive join just when necessary while keeping the original primary ID in the select.

Thank you kindly, everyone!